# Chrome 61 Breakpoints Move after initial hit?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Is anyone seeing an issue with Chrome 61 DevTools?

Here's the scenario:  I have 4 breakpoints in a small section of code. During the first run-through, the first BP is hit appropriately. Upon returning to same code, the top BP moves up a few lines to the top of the current JS section and the code stops there. If out leave the moved BP where it is and try to add another BP in the original position, it will not let you unless you first remove the "moved" BP and then you can re-add the BP. No code changes or anything in this interim that might prompt this.

[image]

I've never had this issues before in previous versions of Chrome. I've googled and searched SO and can't find any mention of this... Maybe I am just lucky?

Comment: Link to repro? Also, are you using sourcemaps?

Comment: Don't have a link to repro - still trying to find out more about it on my own - just wondered if anyone else experienced anything similar. Not using sourcemaps.